# SQL , how to delete the duplicate row and find the min(timeIn) and max(timeOut)

Tags: sql-server

I just want to ask question on how to manage the duplicate row with the different `timeIn` and `timeOut`. I mean, the result should be no duplicate row with same `id` but at the same time the `timeIn` for that particular person should be the minimum `timeIn` and the `timeOut` should be the last `timeOut`. The `attDate` must be on same day. How the query should be done, any ideas?

Here some of my simple code:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, attend_date, Time_in, Time_out,
    count(1) as Count_person
FROM 
    employee
WHERE 
    attDate = '12/01/2015' AND Time_out IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    id, name, attend_date, Time_in, Time_out
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) > 1
```

//note. I'm just a beginner and trying to improve myself.

Comment: Please add your table structure as well.

Comment: tq wewesthemenance.                                                                shree.pat18- how to add the table structure? i still not really pro- in using this thing. any advise ?

Comment: can you add some sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the latest `time_in` and last `time_out`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN_Time_in = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, attDate ORDER BY Time_in),
        RN_Time_Out = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, attDate ORDER BY Time_Out DESC)
    FROM employee
)
SELECT *
FROM Cte
WHERE
    RN_Time_in = 1 
    AND RN_Time_Out = 1
```